# Is there a significant difference between ServiceRegistry and ServiceLoader

Tags: java

In Java there are two classes that seem to implement the same behaviour:

- [java.util.ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)
- [javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.html)

Do they behave different? It seems odd to me that the IEEE used the ImageIO-ServiceRegistry in an environment not related to images (They use it in [HLA (High Level Architecture)](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1516/1516.1-2010/), a framework for publishing objects over the net. If you don't want to extract the java-API-zip you can see it extracted in [portico](https://github.com/openlvc/portico/blob/master/codebase/src/java/portico/hla/rti1516e/RtiFactoryFactory.java) ).

Comment: Good question. Regarding the behavior and the question why someone might use the ImageIO-Registry for non-Image-tasks: The ImageIO-registry is (obviously) far more powerful, and allows DE-registering services, specifying orderings etc. Regarding the question of why they both exist: The `ServiceLoader` was introduced much later (in Java 1.6), and might thus be considered as a "simplified `ServiceRegistry`" (which is also not "suggested to be used for images", in contrast to the `ServiceRegistry` with its `imageio` package name...)